# What algorithm struts2 use to generate randomized token?

Tags: java, struts2, struts, interceptor, struts2-interceptors

Struts  is having `TokenInterceptor` and `TokenSessionStoreInterceptor` which uses token generated on jsp by `<s:token></s:token>` tag , shown below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="66BKG349UZRZKKFH7NFSNOCJGIX0UPST" />
```

What `algorithm` it `uses` to generate token randomly.

Answer (score 3):

When i went through the source code, There is a static method -  `generateGUID()` in [org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.3.15.1/org/apache/struts2/util/TokenHelper.java#TokenHelper) Class, which is used to create the token

```
public static String generateGUID() {
        return new BigInteger(165, RANDOM).toString(36).toUpperCase();
    }
```

Here RANDOM is referencing a new Random() instance member. When I tested the `generateGUID()` method, it generated the following similar tokens below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how Struts2 is generating token code

```
BigInteger(165, RANDOM).toString(36).toUpperCase();
```

have a look at `generateGUID()` method in [TokenHelper](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.3.15.1/org/apache/struts2/util/TokenHelper.java#TokenHelper)